# How to get counter incremented in apply loop

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to make a counter count each row of a data frame which column 1 needs to equal "vsrv11" and  column 3 must is a date that needs to have year 2017.
So I did this code and the counter increments inside the if statement but for every iteration of the loop the counter becomes 0 again.

```
count <- 0

funcao.teste <- function (x) {
    if (x[1] == "vsrv11" && substring(x[3],0,4) == "2017") {
        count <<- count + 1
    }
}

apply(vpnsessions, 1, funcao.teste, count)
```

Comment: Basic answer is to not do that. Multiple bad, seriously inefficient practices.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I'd advise against using global variables and also, you could check this with simple filtering.

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c("vsrv11", rnorm(10)), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 y = rnorm(100),
                 z = as.character(sample(c(2017, 2018), 100, replace = TRUE)))


nrow(df[df[, 1] == "vsrv11" & grepl("2017", df[, 3]), ])
```

or just

```
sum(df[, 1] == "vsrv11" & grepl("2017", df[, 3]))
```

Comment: The second one is the better practice. The first one constructs a dataframe with all the columns in the original, while the second one just builds two logical vectors.

Answer (score 0):

In the `tidyverse` you can perform such an operation using `dplyr::count`:

```
# Sample data
vpnsessions <- data.frame(
    srv = "vsrv11",
    id = c(rep("2017_abc", 10), rep("2018_def", 8)),
    stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr);
count(vpnsessions, year = substr(id, 1, 4))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  year      n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 2017     10
#2 2018      8
```

Note how `count` counts the number of occurrences of `id`s. It's easy to extract relevant rows from the resulting `data.frame`/`tibble`.

To nitpick, in R indexing starts with `1` not with `0`, so `substring(..., 0, 4)` from your code should be `substring(..., 1, 4)`.